# Laravel Weblee\Mandrill\MandrillServiceProvider' class not found

Tags: laravel, mandrill

I am trying to "merge" Mandrill in Laravel. I always get the same error on my page. `Class 'Weblee\Mandrill\MandrillServiceProvider'` not found. The weird thing is that I did name the class in my **config.app**.

Steps that I did.

1. Mandrill template and stuff around
2. Complete .env file with the data it needs.
3. Included "weblee/mandrill": "dev-master" en my composer.json after laravel/framework
4. 2 folders in vendor, weblee and Mandrill.
5. added provider and alias
6. composer update composer dump-autoload/ composer install ==> returning error Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

`[RuntimeException] Error Output: PHP Fatal error: Class Weblee\Mandrill\MandrillServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146`

This is my config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
 Weblee\Mandrill\MandrillServiceProvider::class,
 ],

'aliases' => [
     *Other aliases*
     'MandrillMail' => 'Weblee\Mandrill\MandrillFacade',
],
```

cmposer.json

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "weblee/mandrill": "dev-master"
},
rest of code
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant sections of your composer.json file to your post?

Comment: You did do a `composer update` right? Maybe try a `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: yes it returns this: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Weblee\Mandrill\MandrillServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/vend
  or/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146

Comment: Could you just try to remove your vendor folder en run `composer install`to see if that solves your problem? This will reinstall all your dependencies.

Comment: Also, please post your complete composer.json file instead of just a piece

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to do this

First, install weblee package using composer.json file.

Add this in your composer.json file

> "require": {
>
> ```
>     "php": "^7.1.3",
>
>     "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
>
>     "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
>
>     "weblee/mandrill": "dev-master"
>
> },
> ```

And after that run `composer update`

then add your `Weblee\Mandrill\MandrillServiceProvider::class,` in `config\app.php`

One more thing

```
'aliases' => [
     *Other aliases*
     'MandrillMail' => Weblee\Mandrill\MandrillFacade::class,
],
```

Don't use single quotes